# Не вызывать отправку формы по нажатию на кнопку внутри нее

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я создаю реакт компонент, содержащий в себе элементы, одним из которых является форма содержащая кнопки. Так как кнопки внутри формы, по-умолчанию, они пытаются отправить post-запрос. Мне нужно остановить процесс отправки по нажатию на кнопку. Так же по нажатию на кнопку должна вызываться моя функция.
 Не знаю как одновременно по нажатию вызвать нужную мне функцию и отменить отправку.
Код создания кнопки:

```
React.createElement(
  "button",
  {className:"btn",onClick:this.signUpState},
  'Sign In'
),
```

Вот код функции, вызываемой по нажатию на кнопку:

```
this.signUpState=()=>{
 console.log("Hello!");
};
```

Остановить отправку можно с помощью метода :

> e.preventDefault();

Как это записать в код?
Были попытки написать так:https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/156435/

Comment: Есть 2 способа: 1. Вы можете поймать событие onSubmit на форме и обработать его. 2. Обработать onClick на кнопке. В обоих случаях, если вы хотите избежать стандартного поведения контролла, вам нужно вызвать preventDefault() у события (event). В примере из jsfiddle вы делаете верно. Что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная причина такого поведения - если у вашей кнопки не стоит `type="button"` то по умолчанию считается `type="submit"`. Отсюда и автоматическая отправка формы по нажатию.

Поскольку в реакте вы работаете с компонентами и их состоянием, то лучше вообще избавиться от `<form>`, чтобы избежать нестандартного поведения. Поскольку из-за стандартного поведения форм, будет `Submit` не только на кнопке, но и на `Enter` в любом из `input`

Если же форма нужна, то событие надо ловить не на кнопке, а на форме.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
    ...
</form>

onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: e.preventDefault();

Comment: Да, спасибо, исправил